# Send Objective-C message to C void *

Tags: objective-c, c

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to send objective-c message to C void * from C function?
2. Is it possible to hint void * with `<SomeProtocol>` in C-function declaration? In function body?

(pseudocode)

```
// myfunc.h
void myfunc(void *object, int param);

// myfunc.c
void myfunc(void *object, int param) {
    // desired (pseudocode):
    // [<SomeProtocol>(id)object method:param];
}

// objective-c controller
# include "myfunc.h"
// ....
@implementation

- (void)visible_to_outer_world {
    Object *o = [Object new];
    myfunc(o, 5);
}

// ....
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to send an Objective-C message to a `void *` from a C function?

Not sure why you would want it, but if you're compiling as Objective-C:

```
void bar(void *ptr)
{
    // MRC version:
    [(id)ptr someMessage];

    // ARC (alias "ugly") version:
    [(__bridge id)ptr someMessage];
}

Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
bar(foo);
```

> Is it possible to hint `void *` with `<SomeProtocol>` in a C function declaration? In a function body?

No.

Comment: This only works if you are not using ARC. Remember to include a bridged cast if ARC is enabled.

Comment: Even using obj-c methods in pure c functions is sometimes very differt. For example forward declarations are needed.

Comment: @Sulthan 'objc methods in pure c function' does not compute. Unless you are calling the runtime equivalents, there is no way to have objective-c in pure C (trust me, I've done it the hard way).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII of course, you are right. Ignore the "pure" word. Was typing without thinking.

Comment: After short investigation about protocols decided that `id<Knob> context = (__bridge id)inContext;` in function body is enough for me

Comment: I wouldn't call ARC "ugly", I'd call the ARC requirement of using `__bridge` to be "exceedingly pedantic", which is damned useful when working along the border of ObjC and C or C++.   We've already seen a vast reduction in fragility in our codebase by this pedantic requirement (translating to a reduction in crashes).